# NestedScrollView scrolls to top on Recyclerview resized

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

I have a NestedScrollView containing a LinearLayout and a RecyclerView (both inside a RelativeLayout).

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scroll">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lay_account">


        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/lay_total"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/total"
                    android:id="@+id/lblTotal"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_eurakostheme_color"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>


            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/txtTotalAmount"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_extra_extra_large"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textColor="@color/eurakostheme_color"/>

                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_extra_extra_large"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:src="@drawable/coin_eurakos"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/divisor"
                android:background="@color/dividerColor"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lay_total"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_below="@id/lay_total"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rclBasketAmounts"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="10dp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

After loading the data into the RecyclerView, I need to change it's height programmatically like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    50 + ((int) (baskets.length * getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.list_height_small))));

lay_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lay_total.getId());
recyclerView.setLayoutParams(lay_params);
recyclerView.setAdapter(new ListBasketAmountAdapter(baskets));
```

The problem is when the data has finished loading the NestedScrollView scrolls automatically scrolls to the top of the RecyclerView, hiding the LinearLayout above it. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You should never put a `RecyclerView` in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? Im having the same problem

Comment: not yet, tried almost everything

Comment: @JaredRummler Could you explain the reason? Also, does this apply to NestedScrollView? Do you mean not to add it directly to a scrollview, what if I added a recyclerview inside a cardview which is inside LinearLayout which is inside NestedScrollView?

Comment: Also, what if the recyclerview is set to horizontal not vertical, I believe this rule won't apply.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

After several days I've found a solution to the problem. You just need to add the `descendantFocusability` in the first layout under the `ScrollView` like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lay_account"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
```

Comment: Thank you, in my case after a long day of search, your answer solved the problem, but I have a vertical LinearLayout that contains a fixed size ImageView (Which causes this effect).

Comment: This solution works but keep in mind if there's an `EditText` in child views then it won't be focusable.

Comment: Thank you so much. A day and half I've spent looking for a solution to this. I'd never heard of that attribute, but it solved my problem instantly.

Answer (score 18):

The solution given by kevings14 works but it wasn't helpful in my case. I've a `RecyclerView` + a couple of `EditText` under `NestedScrollView`, when I added

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in main layout under scroll view. I was unable to focus `EditText`.

Then I came up with this solution, which worked for me.

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Answer (score 5):

> In my case, I use multiple RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView. Then
>   it does not work for me. So my solution is, When my data update complete then I just scroll to  top,

```
yourList.setAdapter(yourListAdapter);

scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
         //scrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a nestedscrollview that would get scrolled up by itself. In the post run method of the recyclerview, I scrolled the nestedscrollview to (0,0) and all good.

```
    rvComments.setAdapter(adapterComment); 
    rvComments.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    });
```

---