# Allow recycling items with RecyclerView within NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have the following layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/expert_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/expert_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/expert_appbar_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark"
            app:contentScrim="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/expert_appbar_backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/privacy_gray"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:foreground="@drawable/bg_gradient"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:src="@drawable/bar" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/expert_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/LightToolbarPopup">

                <Space
                    android:id="@+id/circle_collapsed_target"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/double_spacing">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/expert_profile_name"
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/quad_spacing"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:text="Rick Nelson" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/expert_places"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_picks_list" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/expert_avatar_logo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/expert_avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/expert_avatar_size"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/expert_avatar_position"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/larry"
        app:collapsedTarget="@id/circle_collapsed_target"
        app:layout_behavior="com.myapp.transition.AvatarImageLayoutBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see there is a `CollapsingToolbar` within a `CoordinatorLayout`, then a `NestedScrollView` which contains a `CardView` with some info and then a `RecyclerView` with an arbitrary number of items.

I want the header to scroll up until its not seen anymore, effectively hiding below the `AppBar` and only show up at the top of the `RecyclerView` scroll.

This behaviour works nicely but by being within the `NestedScrollView`, `RecyclerView` is not recycling anymore so with ~100 items it already fills in the memory and my app starts slowing down and dragging.

With `RecyclerView` implementing `NestedScrollViewChild` one would expect they would've prepared it to work with `NestedScrollView`, but apparently this is expected and `RecyclerView` stops being a `RecyclerView` when used in combination with that.

Is there any way to circumvent this?

I am aware of other solutions such as putting my `cardview` header within the `appbar` or as a different `itemview` type in the recycler view but those options also have drawbacks and they are not valid for me.

I dont understand how something so basic is so hard to do with Android.

Comment: Yes, NSV keeps in memory all you fill in. So it is bad to put RV there. Try to avoid NSV or RV. I don't see obstacles to remove NSV from your layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView does not Recycling Views when use it inside NestedScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590651/recyclerview-does-not-recycling-views-when-use-it-inside-nestedscrollview)

Comment: It is not cause none of the solutions fix my issue, also all of them are just hacking around it, not actually solving it

Comment: @CoolMind please explain how to achieve desired behavior without the NSV

Comment: @GabrielSanmartin, you have NSV with 2 items one above another (CV and RV). You can add `CardView` as a part of RV. I mean it can be a header of the list. You can search about a header in RV (like a header in `ListView`). Or simply set different `ViewHolder`s in RV.

Comment: As I said in my question, that does not work in my scenario. This has drawbacks associated with it. Also that is just hacking around the problem, not fixing.

Comment: @GabrielSanmartin, you can post images that will describe why solutions you mentioned are not suitable. Maybe we will help, but I doubt.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?