# Show View below RecyclerView after scrolling all items down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-coordinatorlayout

I have `RecyclerView` which contains `Users` and I need button "Add user" at the bottom of `RecyclerView` (should looks like last item of `RecyclerView` and must be scrollable).

What is the best way to achieve this? Add new `itemViewType` to my `Adapter`? Or maybe there is more simple way with `CoordinatorLayout` (to scroll view below `RecyclerView` after one was scrolled all items down, if it is possible)? Second way is really convenient to show scrollable headers with `RecyclerView`.

Comment: why not using std [floating action button](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html)? more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button)

Comment: @pskink Design things. And also I'm interesing is it possible to add ViewGroup below scrolled recyclerView not using NestedScrollView, of course

Comment: so, yes, use a different "item view type" - or you could do similar effect using `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`

Comment: ItemDecoration sounds strange:D

Comment: yes, sounds strange, but it doesnt require multiple item view types

Comment: @pskink can you show a simple example or post link to explanation please?

Comment: https://medium.com/@paulnunezm/working-with-recyclerview-and-multiple-view-types-bb1e7dfc6993

Comment: @pskink I mean how to use ItemDecoration as "ViewType" but thanks :D

Comment: google("footer ItemDecoration")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should add another `ViewType` with its `ViewHolder`. Here is a link to an answer where everything is explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/6329985

Comment: What if I would have more complex "footer" of RecyclerView or even few "footers"? Should I put all of it to RecyclerView as different viewTypes? There is no way to use CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: You should put them inside `RecyclerView` and add different viewTypes for every single item you want to use. If you would like to use `RecyclerView` inside another layout wraped in `NestedScrollView`, there would be a problem with view recycling (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590651/recyclerview-does-not-recycling-views-when-use-it-inside-nestedscrollview). Don't try to complicate your problem.

Comment: No, I just get rid of NestedScrollView:D But adding these viewTypes is so weard especially if they have nothing in common. And if I want to use this UserAdapter in other Activity/Fragment where I don't need to have this viewTypes. It's simple in this case with one button, but if there is more views..

Comment: It's not weird. You can always create another adapter or create adapter which will build itself depending on items passed via list, something like universal adapter. If you won't use `NestedScrollView` then you can't set `RecyclerView` height to match parent casue it will fill whole screen size and buttons below `RecyclerView` will be hidden. There is a point why `RecyclerView` can support different view types :)

Comment: Okay, and what can you say about adding "headers" at the AppBarLayout inside CoordinatorLayout with scroll flags? It will scroll up when recyclerView scrolls. RecyclerView is still "recycler" and everything looks good. Or it's bad practice and I should also put "header" to another viewType in Adapter? For example, "header" is Group (image, name) which has Users in RecyclerView. I should pass to Adapter Group and Users list?

Comment: Putting "headers" like that is a bad idea becasue it will complicate your layout  which is not needed here. Remeber that you should write your code to be eaisly extendable. Don't complicate your life. Your problem here is pretty simple and can you solve it just like I told in previous posts. As for other questions, you should create another post(s) for them.

Comment: Thank you for explanations :) I just never seen an examples with code of what I meaning: "Header Layout, some stuff.." -> RecyclerView with one or similar view types -> "Footer Layout, etc.." and all of it is in one RecyclerView. Well, I will try harder:D Or share link about it if you have one, please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187113/discussion-between-dawidj-and-lifed).