# Multiple RecyclerView In NestedScrollView Freez The UI When Trying to SetAdapter

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, android-recyclerview

In my Fragment i have three RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView I am using `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){ }` to get the data from API but after successfully get the data when i am trying to set adapter to RecyclerView but it freez the UI for 1-3 seconds.

Comment: I would suggest you to not use recyerlview in scrollview. But you can have one parent rv and some nested child rv

Comment: I used  multiple  RecyclerViews in one UI before.  How much datas you set to the adaper at one time? Contains huge image？ If the data is too huge which large memory is occupied, it may freez the UI. If data is too large, you could try the Paging of JetPack https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/paging

Comment: @Raghunandan why not to use recyclerview in scrollview? can you give me a good reference and example for what you saying?

Comment: @HamidSj if you recycyler view in nested scrollview you loose the recycler views are not recycled. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590651/recyclerview-does-not-recycling-views-when-use-it-inside-nestedscrollview. i think the general rule that applies to listview also applies to recylerview